# Will this cause an issue when I plan now to go to out of US then return to the US?

Tags: usa

I have departed the US from Florida to some island such as Puerto Rico by cruise arrivals/departures, and the departure location in my I-94 history says "unavailable". I've now returned to the US.

Will this cause an issue when I plan to go to out of the US then return?

Comment: Just keep a copy of the cruise itinerary and receipt with you when you re-enter the USA, to show the immigration agent upon request. It'll also be helpful if you had an entry stamp to another country. Please note that  Puerto Rico is a US territory so it doesn't count as departing the USA.

Comment: Note also that travel to most neighbouring islands do not reset your time spent in the US under VWP rules.

Answer (score 3):

Puerto Rico is part of the US. From an immigration standpoint, a cruise trip from Florida to Puerto Rico is the same as a cruise from Florida to Texas. If the time before, during and after your Puerto Rico visit exceed your allowable admissions period then you have overstayed in the US. This will likely cause significant problems if you try to re-enter. If you are from a US visa waiver country, you must now apply for a visa for all future US trips. If you entered the US on a visa, that visa is now null and void and you must apply for a new US visa.